# Combining packets of different layers

Tags: bytefield

I am starting with bytefield package.

I'd like to combine differents byte layers, for example, how this:

[image: First option].

Or this:

[image: Second option].

Can someone put a similar example?

Thanks
Best regards
Oscar

Answer (score 1):

You can fake it with some borderless `bytebox`es

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bytefield}
\begin{document}
\begin{bytefield}{15}
\begin{leftwordgroup}{MAC}
\bitbox[]{5}{}&\bitbox{3}{FCF} & \bitbox{3}{Seq.}&\bitbox{4}{FCS}
\end{leftwordgroup}\\
\bitbox[]{5}{}&\bitbox[]{1}{\raggedright$\vdots$}&\bitbox[]{7}{}&\bitbox[]{2}{\raggedleft$\vdots$}\\[1ex]
\begin{leftwordgroup}{PHY}
\bitbox{5}{Preamble} & \bitbox{10}{MPDU}
\end{leftwordgroup}
\end{bytefield}
\end{document}
```

[image]